# Transactional versus Dimensional model for file upload web application -- preferred approach?

Tags: database-design, dimensional-modeling

For a web application whose sole purpose is to allow users to upload raw file data at any time (to database tables), does a transactional or dimensional model make more sense for such an application?

Some reporting is done off the data at this time but it is very minimal.  If that changes in the future (such that reporting becomes more pervasive), does that change the model you suggest?

Total space for the database 100GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your data, and how you want to store it and access it later to report off it. Your database itself doesn't need to be geared specifically to one or the other, rather you can have tables that are transactional, dimensional, or simultaneously both depending on your use case.

In general, if you're doing some sort of reporting off the data, then normalizing your data with dimensions is helpful for performance, flexibility, and maintenance. But a transactional table can still store references to dimensions to represent the "facts" / qualitative portion of the data to maintain normalization. Or they can even directly store the dimensions inside them themselves, albeit being a denormalized representation of the data from the former.

See the following for two different schemas representing a transactional table that stores dimensions vs being normalized and storing references to those dimensions (T-SQL syntax):

**Denormalized**

```
CREATE TABLE DenormalizedTransactions AS
(
    TransactionId BIGINT,
    ItemName VARCHAR(100),
    ItemType VARCHAR(25)
    Quantity INT
);
```

**Normalized**

```
CREATE TABLE NormalizedTransactions AS
(
    TransactionId BIGINT,
    ItemId INT,
    ItemTypeId INT
    Quantity INT
);

CREATE TABLE Items AS
(
    ItemId INT,
    ItemName VARCHAR(100),
    Description VARCHAR(1000)
);

CREATE TABLE ItemTypes AS
(
    ItemTypeId INT,
    ItemType VARCHAR(25)
);
```

Comment: You mention 'But a transactional table can still store dimensions to represent the "facts" / qualitative portion of the data to maintain normalization.'  Do you have a resource that I can use to show how this is accomplished?  Thx.

Comment: @tale852150 Sorry I wrote that part in haste and just clarified it a bit. Though either way is possible (storing dimensions on a transactional table, or storing them in a normalized table that is referenced by the transactional table). I added examples T-SQL queries for each case.

Comment: Is there any online course and/or book that goes into this approach you mention?

Comment: @tale852150 Unfortunately I couldn't find much in regards to using one, [this](https://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/transaction-dimension/) was the closest I found which mostly talks about how to normalize an existing Transactional Dimensions Table. Likely this is because normalization is best practice and denormalized structures are generally not recommended (except for special cases).

Comment: Thx.  That will help and it’s much better than what I have now.

Comment: @tale852150 No problem! Any other questions, feel free to ask and I'll do my best to answer. Best of luck!

Comment: Can you upvote my OP?